# in python which would be the fastest way to compare / test with an lists

Tags: arrays, optimization, data-structures, comparison, python-3.2

In my code the lists will eventually end up will all elements empty. Which is what I am testing for, are all elements == ''.

The size of the lists can vary with input.

The two test I was considering are an equality test, and using the list.count() function. Which will be faster at runtime.

I am new to python so how things are done in the back ground are not that familiar to me. My assumption is that **Test 2** will be faster if it does not iteratively check each element to do the comparison. As the data in the lists can vary from an empty string to a over string of over 100 chars the simple check done by **Test 1** count('') could also be very fast.

Sample code to set up my variables for testing.

```
mylist = [''] * 33
testlist = []
testlist.extend('' * mylist.__len__())
testlist.count('')
33
mylist.count('')
33
```

Which of the following test is going to be faster.

**Test 1**

```
if mylist.count('') == 33:
    do some thing

while mylist.count('') !=33:
    do some thing
```

**Test 2**

```
if mylist == testlist:
    do some thing

while mylist != testlist:
    do some thing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't describe the problem that you are actually trying to solve, but are you setting list entries to the empty string in order to mark them as finished, so that you don't process them again?

If that's the case, then you may get better results by using a different data structure. For example, perhaps you could use a [`set`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset), and [`remove`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.remove) items when you are done with them. Then you can just test to see if your set is empty, which is a constant-time operation.

But we need to know more about what you are trying to do in order to be able to help you.

If you just want to figure out which of two implementations is faster, Python's [`timeit` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) contains functions for timing execution of code. For example:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> l1 = [''] * 1000
>>> l2 = [''] * 1000
>>> timeit(lambda:l1 == l2)
4.670141935348511
>>> timeit(lambda:l1.count('') == len(l1))
4.50224494934082
```

so it looks like these two approaches take almost exactly the same time in this case (as you might have guessed). But in the case where the list is not full of empty strings, `==` is faster (because when it finds a mismatch it can return `False` immediately without having to check any more list elements):

```
>>> l3 = ['a'] + [''] * 999
>>> timeit(lambda:l3.count('') == len(l3))
4.379799842834473
>>> timeit(lambda:l3 == l2)
0.19073486328125
```

Comment: timeit looks useful. I will go and experiment with some of my code to see how it runs.